# Duplicate Excel File with R

Tags: r, excel, duplicates, xlsx

I´m currently looking for a way to duplicate excel files with R (I guess it might work with xlsx but I didnt figure out how to yet). Copying the values out of the cells into a new file or loading the information into R wont work for my usecase. I didnt find anything usefull so far and it´s the first time that I code in R so I hope somebody can help!

EDIT: I added the code that I used for the advice with file.copy which doesnt seem to work for me so far

```
path_cwd <- getwd()  
path_cwd

#gibt Ordner mit Excel Datei an
path_other <- "C:\\UserData\\z003xbys\\Documents\\Excel-R"
#gibt files im aktuellen working directory zurück
destination <- dir(path_other, "*.xlsx", ignore.case = TRUE)

file.copy(destination, path_cwd, overwrite = TRUE, copy.mode = TRUE, copy.date  
 = TRUE)
```

Greetings
Luis

Comment: Why not just copy the file with `file.copy` ?

Comment: Just tried it out but it seems to damage the excel file. When I try to open the copied version I get a error message which basically says that the "data extension/ format is not valid and that I should check if the file is corrupted".

Edit: I just added the code in the original post

Comment: I used your code (except for changing the path for my machine) and it successfully copied 3 xlsx files.   The number of bytes is exactly the same for the originals and the copies. Did the number of bytes change for your files?

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick response again! Yea the number of bytes changed to 0. Maybe the file.copy function doesnt work properly because of a special plugin that my company uses called smartview. Anyways I found a solution: I load the workbook into R and change the cell values there with "addDataFrame", when I´m finished I just use "saveWorkbook" with a different name. This seems to work so far :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy an Excel file with the following approach :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
path_Excel_File_Input <- "D:\\file1.xlsx"
path_Excel_File_Output <- "D:\\file2.xlsx"

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File_Input)

xlWbk$SaveAs(path_Excel_File_Output)
```